# How to show a button payment method according to the selected customer?

Tags: javascript, odoo, pos

I have created a field called credit in 'res.partner' model, that is loaded in Point of Sale. I show this field on payment screen (specifically on a button payment method) but when the customer is changed the credit field doesn't.

I know the problem is the paymentmethods area doesn't refresh when i change a customer but I don't know how to do it.

javascript :

```
models.load_fields('res.partner', ['refund_credit']);
```

xml:

```
<t t-name="PaymentScreen-Paymentmethods">
    <div class='paymentmethods'>
        <t t-foreach="widget.pos.cashregisters" t-as="cashregister">
            <div class="button paymentmethod" t-att-data-id="cashregister.journal_id[0]">
                <t t-esc="cashregister.journal_id[1]" />
                <t t-esc="widget.pos.get_client().refund_credit"/>
            </div>
        </t>
    </div>
</t>
```

Comment: Welcome [cgonzalezbrito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9371798/cgonzalezbrito)! Typically you are going to want to show a little more work when asking questions in SO. For instance, show the actual javascript code. A simple jQuery event handler would solve this problem. Use the `jQuery('element').change` or `jQuery.on'change ','element', function());`  or the `jQuery.click()` depending on the situation...